# QGIS KDE (Heatmap) TIF file --> Open in ArcGIS in order to use Kernel Interpolation With Barriers

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation, kernel-density

So I've created KDE **.tif** files in QGIS, but there are currently no plugins available in QGIS, which takes into account barriers when creating KDE density rasters for species.

I can bring the .tif file into ArcGIS 10.4 and it is visible, however when I open the *Kernel Interpolation With Barriers* Tool in ArcGIS, the .tif file is not visible in the drop down menu [INPUT FEATURES].

I am wondering can I convert the QGIS .tif file into a file that is usable in ArcGIS? and can then be used with the *Kernel Interpolation With Barriers* Tool?

Comment: It [this the tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/geostatistical-analyst/kernel-interpolation-with-barriers.htm) you are trying to use? Then input should be points, not a raster: "The input point features containing the z-values to be interpolated.
 Feature Layer"

Comment: You're right BERA. Thank you. So it turns out the _Kernel Interpolation With Barriers_ Tool is just that, an Interpolation tool, not a density tool. So I need to create the KDE first (without barriers) and then use the _Kernel Interpolation With Barriers_ Tool. Am I correct?